# How can I have the returns integer(0) to come back as Null and set d to be length of 1?

Tags: r

```
fxz <- function (x,d=2)
{
    if(d !=2) d = d
    which(x %% d ==0)
}

> fxz(x=2:12,d=13)
integer(0)
```

I used the modulo operator inside the which statement to returns all the position of numbers with 0 remainders by the divisor. Since it returns `integer(0)`, How can I have it return null instead?

On another thought. I want the function to stop and output a warning message when d is anything but a single numeric value. 
I been trying stuff like "if d doesn't equal to a number, stop("message")".

Thanks for the help. I'm pretty new to R programming

Comment: One option is that you check `length` of return value of `which`. Something like `length(which(t %% 2 ==0))`. If `length()` is `0` then you return `NA_integer_`.

Comment: I been trying implement that function, but kept on getting errors and now I been clarified with an example. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your function with a check for the class of d and the length of the result at the end:

```
fxz <- function (x, d=2) {

  # Check d is an integer or numeric
  if (!(is.integer(d) | is.numeric(d))) {
    stop("The d argument must be numeric")
  }

  result = which(x %% d ==0)

  # If result has length 0 return NULL instead of result
  if (length(result) == 0) {
    return(NULL)
  } else {
    return(result)
  }

}
```

And example outputs:

```
> fxz(x=2:12, d=2)
[1]  1  3  5  7  9 11
> fxz(x=2:12, d=13)
NULL
> fxz(x=2:12, d="hey")
Error in fxz(x = 2:12, d = "hey") : The d argument must be numeric
```

Comment: Wow! very nice. I like how you nested the length test of "results"  to return a NULL. I been trying to do something like that, but kept on getting errors, because I did not define "results" like you did.

Comment: Thanks, glad it was useful. If you're satisfied with the answer check the tick next to the answer to accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

This function stops and outputs a warning message when x is anything but a single numeric value

```
fxz <- function (x) {

  # Check d is an integer or numeric and length == 1
  stopifnot( is.numeric(x), (length(x) == 1) ) 

}
```

Comment: Oh! Very efficient. I gotta look into more of the stopifnot function. So the first part defines it to be numeric and the second part defined with length() == 1 means it can only be a single numeric value. Thanks Esteban :) probably will use this in the future.